# Assembly calculate sine example. nasm 16 dos

Tags: assembly, draw, nasm, angle, dos

I'm looking for example how to calculate sine using coprocessor.
I've found function:

```
CalcSin 
        fld     long [angle]            ; st(0) = angle 
        fsin                            ; st(0) = sin(angle)  (angle is in radians) 
        fstp    long [SinX]             ; SinX = sin(angle)
```

I want to draw sine and I need to Y in `ax` and X in `bx`.
X will be no problem, because I will make loop for, but with Y I have a problem. X will be from example 0 to 350 (like a pixels).
How to calculate it and have Y for pixel if for example sin (30 deg) is 1/2.
How to round result to have good coordinate?

---

**Edit:**
I'm sorry, but I when I run your code it shows me no sinus, but 2 lines. I don't know what I'm doing wrong now

```
    segment .data

    segment .code
..start:
    mov ax, 13h 
    int 10h               ; switch to 320x200 mode

    mov ax, 0a000h        ; The offset to video memory
    mov es, ax            ; We load it to ES through AX,
                          ; because immediate operation
                          ; is not allowed on ES

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

DrawWave:
    mov ebx, y  ; EBX = &y
    mov ecx, 0

    ; let st(1) = 2*PI/640
    fldpi               ; st(0) = PI
    fidiv dword [step]  ; st(0)/160 = 0.009817...
    fldz                ; st(0) = 0.0, st(1) = 0.00045...

    .loop:
        fld st0   ; duplicate the x on the top
        fsin        ; st(0) = sin x

        fimul dword [imgHeight]     ; st(0) = y*240
        fiadd dword [imgHeight]     ; eliminate negative coordinate by translating the wave vertically          
        fistp dword [y]             ; store y to ´y´

        fadd st0, st1           ; add the step value to x, doing the step

        ;draw pixel at [*EAX:ECX]
        push ax
        push bx
        push cx
        call DrawPixel
        pop cx
        pop bx
        pop ax

        inc ecx
        cmp ecx, 320    ; perform 640 steps to draw a single sine wave
        jl .loop

        fstp st0  ;clean up
        fstp st0  ;clean up
    ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    xor ah, ah
    int 16h               ; keyboard (wait for key)

    mov ax, 3
    int 10h               ; go to text mode

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h               ; return to DOS, exit code 0

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; EBX = in &CoordY
; ECX = CoordX  
;DrawPixel:
    ; draw a pixel at [*EBX:ECX]
 ;   ret 
DrawPixel:
    push dx               ; mul changes dx too
    mov ax, cx            ; ax is X coord copy from cx
    mov cx, 320
    mul cx                ; multiply Y (ax) by 320 (one row)
    add ax, bx            ; and add X (bx) (result= dx:ax)
    mov di, ax
    pop dx
    mov dl, 4
    mov [es:di], dl       ; store color/pixel
    ret

    ;CONSTANTS:

step: dw 160        ; 2/320 = 160
imgWidth: dw 320    ; 320px
imgHeight: dw 200/2 ; 200px on half, because Y also gets negative
;VARIABLES:
x: dw 0     ; a tmp place to save X
y: dw 0     ; a tmp place to save Y
```

Comment: ´I want to draw sine´ - what do you mean? Sine wave?

Comment: yes. It will be later sine wave animation. But I want to start from sine wave

Comment: I'm working on my answer.

Comment: Thank you. When I will have my sinus it will be for me easier to put letters on it(my task is sine scroll animation. Letters I have got already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your correctly, you want to draw a sine wave without any translations and scaling. Therefore you can take the `angle` as your `X` coordinate, and the value you get from function `f(x) = sin x` is your `Y` coordinate.

```
; EAX = in &CooordX
; EBX = out &CoordY
SinX:
    fld     qword [eax]           ; st(0) = angle 
    fsin                         ; st(0) = sin(angle)
    fstp    qword [ebx]           ; *ebx = sin(angle) 
    ret
```

Now let's say you want to draw a single wave. That means that `x == 2*PI rad` (a full wave) must be true exactly when drawing the last pixel. With a screen 640 pixels wide, your single step for `x` in drawing loop is `2*PI/640 = 0.009817`. The rest is simple.

```
;CONSTANTS:
step: dw 320        ; 2/640 = 320, omitted PI
imgWidth: dw 640    ; 640px
imgHeight: dw 480/2 ; 480px on half, because Y also gets negative

;VARIABLES:
y: dw 0     ; a tmp place to save Y

DrawWave:
    mov ebx, y  ; EBX = &y
    mov ecx, 0

    ; let st(1) = 2*PI/640
    fldpi               ; st(0) = PI
    fidiv dword [step]  ; st(0)/320 = 0.009817...
    fldz                ; st(0) = 0.0, st(1) = 0.009817...

    .loop:
        fld st(0)   ; duplicate the x on the top
        fsin        ; st(0) = sin x

        fimul dword [imgHeight]     ; st(0) = y*240
        fiadd dword [imgHeight]     ; eliminate negative coordinate by translating the wave vertically          
        fistp dword [y]             ; store y to ´y´

        fadd st(0), st(1)           ; add the step value to x, doing the step

        ;draw pixel at [*EAX:ECX]
        call DrawPixel

        inc ecx
        cmp ecx, 640    ; perform 640 steps to draw a single sine wave
        jl .loop

        fstp st(0)  ;clean up
        fstp st(0)  ;clean up
    ret

; EBX = in &CoordY
; ECX = CoordX  
DrawPixel:
    ; draw a pixel at [*EBX:ECX]
    ret
```

Comment: I have edit my question. I can't see any results. I use NASM 16 DOS and a mode 320x200

Comment: This is only an algorithm for drawing sine wave, not for drawing actual pixels. You must edit `DrawPixel` to display a pixel on specified location when called.

Comment: I thought that X and Y is in ; EBX = Y
; ECX = X  So I write procedure to display pixels(I uses this before), End all programm I later changed on 16 bits

Comment: Where is your Comment? It disappear. I'm sorry for my English, but I'm still learning and it isn't my native language. I'm not sure I could go to chat, because I'm pretty new user and have no to many points.

Comment: Please add some contact information to your profile (email, skype).

Comment: I mailed you, we can use gmail.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents ;-) . X are degrees and Y are scaled (*50) sine-radiants. The (hidden) X-axis is at row 100.

```
segment stack stack
    resb 0x1000

segment .data
    ; no data

segment .code
..start:
main:
    mov ax, data            ; Initialize DS (needed for .exe-program)
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, 0x0A000         ; Segment to video memory
    mov es, ax

    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h                 ; switch to 320x200 mode

    mov cx, 0
    .l1:
    push cx                 ; store CX
    call get_sine
    add ax, 100             ; shift Y to position of X-axis (100)
    mov bx, cx
    call vector_to_memory
    mov di, ax
    mov al, 0x0F            ; white
    mov [es:di], al         ; put pixel
    pop cx                  ; restore CX
    inc cx                  ; CX = CX + 1
    cmp cx, 320             ; right boarder reached?
    jne .l1                 ; no, next degree

    xor ah, ah
    int 16h                 ; keyboard (wait for key)
    mov ax, 3
    int 10h                 ; go to text mode
    mov ax, 0x4C00
    int 21h                 ; return to DOS, exit code 0

get_sine:                   ; Args: CX = angle (degree!)
    push cx                 ; = sub sp, 2 (local stack space), mov [sp], cx
    mov bp, sp              ; BP = SP (local stack space) for FPU-accesses
    fild word [bp]          ; ST(0): CX
    fldpi                   ; ST(0)=Pi, ST(1)=CX
    fmulp                   ; ST(0)=Pi*CX
    mov word [bp], 180
    fidiv word [bp]         ; ST(0)=(Pi*CX)/180 (formula for degree to rad)
    fsin                    ; ST(0)=sine (rad)
    mov word [bp], 50       ; Scale the result by 50 (e.g. 0.8 => 40.0)
    fimul word [bp]         ; ST(0)=sine*scale
    fchs                    ; reverse sign because video counts from top to bottom
    fistp word [bp]         ; store integer with rounding to local stack space
    pop ax                  ; AX = local stack space
    ret                     ; Return: AX = Y (signed!)

vector_to_memory:           ; Args: BX = X, AX = Y
    push dx                 ; mul changes dx too
    mov cx, 320             ; video mode width
    mul cx                  ; DX:AX = AX * CX
    add ax, bx              ; left indentation
    pop dx
    ret                     ; Return: AX = offset in memory
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create and to use an own sine/cosine table, that we can store only one times into a file and for loading and using it many times. The following examples are showing how to create an own sine/cosine table.

```
      Grad    = 360
      Endtab  = 450

segment .data

SINTAB DB Endtab DUP (?,?,?,?)

TEIL   DW 180, ?
I      DW 0, 0

TABNAM DB "Sin.tab"

segment .code

START:    mov     ax, data
          mov     ds, ax
          finit
          call TABLE
          mov     dx, TABNAM
          call MAKDAT
          xor     dx, dx
          mov     cx, Endtab*4
          call WRITE
          call CLOSE
          mov     ax, 4C00h
          int   21h

TABLE:    xor     di, di          ; Create sine table
TAB:      fldpi
          fimul  DWORD[I]
          fidiv  DWORD[TEIL]      ; by 180(INT)
          fsin
          fstp   DWORD[di]
          inc    WORD[I]
          add     di, 4
          cmp    WORD[I], Endtab
          jnz TAB
          ret

MAKDAT:   mov     ah, 3Ch
          xor     cx, cx
          int  21h       ; we hope that no error occur
          mov     bx, ax ; ....but better insert a handling for
          ret

WRITE:    mov     ah, 40h
          int   21h       ; ....also here
          ret

CLOSE:    mov     ah, 3Eh
          int   21h
          ret
```

And it is also possible to create and to use an **integer** sine/cosine table. But the handling of it is a little bit different, because the sine/cosine values are multiplicated and so we have to multiplicate the values that we want to calculate too with the same multiplier and finally we have to devide the result.

```
      Grad    = 360 * 2
      Endtab  = 450 * 2
      Foktor  = 10000h   ; for to replace/shift the floating point of the value

segment .data

SINTAB DB Endtab DUP (?,?,?,?)
TEIL   DW Grad/2, ?
I      DW 0, 0
FAKT   DD Foktor
TABNAM DB "SinInt.tab", 0

segment .code

START:    ; same main-routine

TABLE:    xor     di, di     ; subroutine for to create an integer table
TAB:      fldpi
          fimul  DWORD[I]
          fidiv  DWORD[TEIL]
          fsin
          fimul  DWORD[FAKT]
          fistp  DWORD[di]
          inc    WORD[I]
          add     di, 4
          cmp    WORD[I], Endtab
          jnz TAB
          ret

; same subroutines for create, write and store file
```

For to get a higher accuracy of the calculation (example for a higher screen resolution for to prevent holes) we can simple double the value of the 360 degree for the counter of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for answer and rkhb too. I would give you arrow up if I have enought reputation poinsts. In my way I would also calculate it once and use sine table, but in school they want me to know how to use coprocessor.